# AWK show until first difference

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I want AWK to display everything until the first difference occurs by my criteria in two files.

**File1** line: `C000  4C F5 C5  JMP $C5F5 A:00 X:00 Y:00 P:24 SP:FD CYC:  0 SL:241`

**File2** line: `JMP $C5F5  0x0000c000 A:00 X:00 Y:00 | SP:fd P:24 N0 V0 B0 D0 I1 Z0 C0`

These both lines differ in structure but that's no problem as I can match with a regex:

`awk 'match($0, /P\:\([0-9]+)/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' File1.txt`

This prints me the `P:24` value despite the fact in which column it appears in `File1`.

**What I want**

- compare each line by it's `P:number` value
- stop the output once the P value differs

**EDIT: How the output should look like**

**File1**:

```
A:1 B:2 P:3
A:1 B:2 P:4
A:1 B:2 P:5
```

**File2**:

```
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
A:1 P:55 C:5
```

Output:

```
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
```

As the third line differs. I don't care which file to output, first or second until the first difference by criteria :)

Comment: No. I wan to print all the lines from File1 or File2 whose P values are the same. Once the P:24 and P:12 are compared it should stop outputting the lines.

Comment: Do you want all of the lines from File1 followed by those from File2, or have them interleaved or something else? Is there always a 1-to-1 correspondence between the lines in the 2 files? Post a FEW lines of expected input (say 5 lines for each file) and the expected output.

Comment: Where do the "P:2"s in the output come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ match($0,/P:[0-9]+/); key=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }
NR == FNR { keys[NR]=key; next }
key == keys[FNR] { print; next }
{ exit }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
```

You could make the match() more precise with word boundaries if you have GNU awk:

```
match($0,/\<P:[0-9]+\>/)
```

With other awks it's a bit trickier but here's one alternative based on the idea of saving name:value input in an array:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if (split($i,t,/:/)==2) a[NR==FNR,FNR,t[1]] = t[2] }
NR==FNR { next }
a[1,FNR,"P"] == a[0,FNR,"P"] { print; next }
{ exit }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NR==FNR { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i ~ /P:[0-9]+/) { p[NR] = $i; next } }
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i == p[FNR]) { print; next } }
{ exit }
```

Loop through the fields in the first file and store the "P:..." field into an array, using the line number as the key.

In the second file, look up the value in the array corresponding to the same line number and print the lines which have a matching value.

The `{ exit }` block at the bottom will only be reached if the line in the second file doesn't match.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f match.awk file1 file2
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
```

Comment: idk if it could happen or not, but that'd fail if the input contained a `P` after the `P:<num>` field, e.g. `SP:fd P:24 N0 P V0` or `SP:fd P:24 N0 X:P V0` would result in `p[NR]` containing `V0` instead of `24`.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis that it could be really inefficient to read the entire first file before doing the comparisons, here's a solution which reads the two files in lockstep. I left out lots of error checking, but I put in lots of comments. (Assumes that the object to match is a field in the `awk` sense of what a field is.)

```
$ cat uptodiff.awk
# The *last* command line argument is taken as the second file. We pop that off
# the command line in case it's the only command line argument, in which case
# stdin will implicitly be the first file.
BEGIN{f2=ARGV[--ARGC]}
# This function compares each field with the regex in its argument, and
# returns the first one which matches. If there's no match, it returns nothing.
function get(pat,       i) {
  for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~pat)return $i
}
# For each line in the first file:
#   Get the matching field, read a line from the second file, and get
#   its matching field
{ first=get(PAT); getline <f2; second=get(PAT) }
# If the matching fields are different, we're done;
# otherwise print the line (from the second file, since we replaced $0 above)
first != second{exit}1 

$ awk -f uptodiff.awk PAT='^P:[[:digit:]]+$' file1 file2
A:1 P:3 C:3
A:1 P:4 C:4
```